# Full outer join very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One is todays prices and one is yesterdays prices. There is a job which updates each table over night. Yesterdays prices is a copy of todays before it gets updated.

I am trying to create a table which shows the differences between the tables.

To do this I am using a full outer join. I am filtering down my criteria to make it faster as both tables are over 48 million rows.

My current code is like this.

```
WITH differ AS 
(
    SELECT 
        tAP.CustomerID, tAP.ProductID, yAP.CustomerID AS 'Yest_CustomerID', yAP.ProductID AS 'Yest_ProductID',
        tAP.PDG, tAP.DiscPct1, tAP.DiscPct2, 
        yAP.DiscPct1 AS 'Yest_DiscPct1',
        yAP.DiscPct2 AS 'Yest_DiscPct2',
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),tAP.DiscPct1 - yAP.DiscPct1) AS 'DiscPct1_Difference',
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),tAP.DiscPct2 - yAP.DiscPct2) AS 'DiscPct2_Difference', 
        tAP.internalSPANumber, yAP.internalSPANumber AS 'Yest_InternalSPANumber', tAP.SPAUniqueReference,
        tAP.Project, 
        tAP.ExpiryDate,tAP.Subaddress, tAP.PriceType, yAP.PriceType AS 'Yest_PriceType', tAP.ListPrice, 
        tAP.NettPrice, yAP.NettPrice AS 'Yest_NettPrice',
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),tAP.NettPrice- yAP.NettPrice) AS 'NettPrice_Difference'

    FROM tbl_Prices tAP FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_Prices_Yesterday yAP ON tAP.CustomerId = yAP.CustomerID AND tAP.ProductID = yAP.ProductID
                 AND tAP.PDG = yAP.PDG AND tAP.Project = yAP.Project AND tAP.PriceType = yAP.PriceType

    WHERE   (((tAP.DiscPct1 <> yAP.DiscPct1) 
            OR (tAP.DiscPct2 <> yAP.DiscPct2)
            OR (yAP.CustomerID IS NULL)
            OR (tAP.CustomerID IS NULL)
            OR (tAP.NettPrice <> yAP.NettPrice)
            OR (tAP.InternalSPANumber <> yAP.InternalSPANumber))

            AND 
            (
                tAP.ProductID = '10238610' OR tAP.ProductID = '10238620'
                OR tAP.ProductID = '10238621' OR tAP.ProductID = '10238687' 
                OR tAP.ProductID = '10238688' OR yAP.ProductID = '10238610'
                OR yAP.ProductID = '10238620' OR yAP.ProductID = '10238621'
                OR yAP.ProductID = '10238687' OR yAP.ProductID = '10238688')
            ) 
)

SELECT * INTO tbl_Difference FROM differ
```

Anyway to make this faster?

Comment: do you really need to use a cte for this?

Comment: @Tanner I do as there is more to add after the CTE but for this part I have just put the select into below but I use the CTE to add more into into then put it into a table

Comment: Perhaps you can try a drop table of "yesterday", then make a sp_rename of "today" and run a create of your "today" table for recreate the table.

Comment: All the nonSARGable predicates in you where clause are going to kill your performance here.

Comment: @Tjasun I think you missed the point of my question. The creation of yesterday and update of today is all fine. I am now trying to find the differences between them. So I can compare which prices have changed and by how much etc

Comment: No matter what you do you are going to get full table scans because you have inequality checks in your where clause. When the tables have 48 million rows a scan is NOT going to be anything resembling fast.

Comment: @SeanLange how would you make it SARGable then? At the moment it only takes around 5-10 minutes to get these, however it is causing some problems due to the needs of the query. So I am looking to make it faster and more efficient as well

Comment: Are all the columns of these tables' PKs included in the join condition?  Are any non-PK columns included?

Comment: @JohnBollinger There is no primary keys in the table. It is indexed on ProductID and CustomerID (I've been told) but no primary keys

Comment: It might well improve query performance if there were more supportive indexes than you describe, on both tables.

Comment: If the job updates just specific row in table "today", perhaps you can use an update trigger on "today". This trigger can hold your BL for inserting or not inserting into your "diff" table.

Comment: You have a table that is a 48 million row heap??? If it is only taking 5-10 minutes you should be doing a jig. That is actually a LOT faster than I would have expected.

Comment: (tAP.DiscPct1 < yAP.DiscPct1 OR tAP.DiscPct1 > yAP.DiscPct1) is SARGable and would produce the same result.

Comment: why doesn't your updating script keep the old price in today's table? old prices and price differences are usually queried frequently and it's better to calculate them in the beginning. Even you can't change the "updating script", you can calculate them once and keep them in your new table.

Answer (score 2):

Can you filter the 2 large tables before you try to join them using AND filter in your where?

```
WITH tAPcte AS 
(
    SELECT * -- fields you need
    FROM   tbl_Prices
    WHERE  ProductID IN ('10238610',
                         '10238620',
                         '10238621',
                         '10238687',
                         '10238688')

),
yAPcte AS
(
    SELECT * -- fields you need
    FROM   tbl_Prices_Yesterday
    WHERE  ProductID IN ('10238610',
                         '10238620',
                         '10238621',
                         '10238687',
                         '10238688')
)
differ AS 
(
    SELECT 
        tAP.CustomerID, tAP.ProductID, yAP.CustomerID AS 'Yest_CustomerID', yAP.ProductID AS 'Yest_ProductID',
        tAP.PDG, tAP.DiscPct1, tAP.DiscPct2, 
        yAP.DiscPct1 AS 'Yest_DiscPct1',
        yAP.DiscPct2 AS 'Yest_DiscPct2',
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),tAP.DiscPct1 - yAP.DiscPct1) AS 'DiscPct1_Difference',
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),tAP.DiscPct2 - yAP.DiscPct2) AS 'DiscPct2_Difference', 
        tAP.internalSPANumber, yAP.internalSPANumber AS 'Yest_InternalSPANumber', tAP.SPAUniqueReference,
        tAP.Project, 
        tAP.ExpiryDate,tAP.Subaddress, tAP.PriceType, yAP.PriceType AS 'Yest_PriceType', tAP.ListPrice, 
        tAP.NettPrice, yAP.NettPrice AS 'Yest_NettPrice',
        CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),tAP.NettPrice- yAP.NettPrice) AS 'NettPrice_Difference'

    FROM tAPcte tAP FULL OUTER JOIN yAPcte yAP ON tAP.CustomerId = yAP.CustomerID AND tAP.ProductID = yAP.ProductID
                 AND tAP.PDG = yAP.PDG AND tAP.Project = yAP.Project AND tAP.PriceType = yAP.PriceType

    WHERE   (((tAP.DiscPct1 <> yAP.DiscPct1) 
            OR (tAP.DiscPct2 <> yAP.DiscPct2)
            OR (yAP.CustomerID IS NULL)
            OR (tAP.CustomerID IS NULL)
            OR (tAP.NettPrice <> yAP.NettPrice)
            OR (tAP.InternalSPANumber <> yAP.InternalSPANumber))
)

SELECT * INTO tbl_Difference FROM differ
```

Comment: I have tried that already, I think due to the size of both tables this makes things a lot longer. Especially when I add more products I am trying to find. My plan is to get these products filtered fast first then add more

Comment: try using temp tables instead of ctes

Comment: I tried that as well. And because of the sizes of the tables that came out, I made the temp tables all crash. This is because there can be 10000s of results for today and yesterday but I am only interested in ones that have changed. So there might only be 100s at the end

Comment: Do you have indexes on `ProductID` that would support the suggested additional CTEs?

Comment: There is indexes on ProductID and CustomerID (I've been told only recently took this on)

Comment: In total there is 330000~ productIds. With around 28000~ customers in this table

Comment: That's fine, but how may times would product Id "10238610" show up in the table?